# I'm trying to write a program that gets information from a serial port (it's not a file).

Tags: c, serial-port

I'm starting in C. 
I'm trying to write a program that gets information from a serial port (it's not a file). The serial port is constantly sending information. I wrote a little program but I kept geting segmentation fault:11. The main objective would be to get the information that we are getting by the serial port to be stored in a file. 
Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include <errno.h>   
#include <termios.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int open_port();

main()
{

    printf("\n\nStarting...\n\n");
    open_port();

    return (1);
}

int open_port()
{
    int fd;
    int bytes;
    int string;

    char *input;


    struct termios options;

    /* open usb entry */
    fd = open("/dev/cu.usbserial-FTF6001E", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);


    /* check it could be opened */
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("\n\nopen_port: Unable to open /dev/cu.usbserial-FTF6001E - ");
    }    
    else{

        ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes);
        printf("\n\nbytes: %d\n\n", bytes);



        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

        /* get port options currently set*/
        tcgetattr(fd, &options);

        options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;

        /* Set the baud rates to 19200...*/
        cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
        cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);

        /* Enable the receiver and set local mode...*/
        options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

        /*Set the new options for the port...*/
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

        *input = (char) malloc (string * sizeof(char));

        if (input == 0){

            fputs("\n\nUps! Failed to allocate memory!!!\n\n",stdout);

        }

        if ( fgets (input , 100 , fd) != NULL ){
            puts (input);
            fclose (fd);
        }

        printf("input = %s", input);

    }
```

Comment: You already have a lot of printf statements. Put in more printf statements and see which expression is causing the seg fault. Then if you can't work out how to get around that, ask a question about what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies here:

```
*input = (char) malloc (string * sizeof(char));
```

For a start, you want to assign to `input`, not `*input`. Because `input` is not yet a valid pointer to anywhere, `*input` is undefined behaviour.

However, even once you fix that, you'll have problems <sup>(a)</sup>. Your `string` variable has not been initialised so will be set to whatever rubbish was on the stack when your program starts. That means you're unlikely to be getting the right amount of memory returned from `malloc` anyway.

In addition, you're casting the return value of `malloc` to a `char`! You should never cast the return value of `malloc` (such as to `char *`) in C since it hides certain errors which may cause other problems later on.

You *certainly* shouldn't cast it to a `char` since that will almost certainly lose information. Explicit casting is you telling the compiler that you know what you're doing - I don't think that's quite accurate here :-)

In fact, I'm not sure why you're dynamically allocating the memory at all since you only ever read in 100 bytes to it. Ditch the `malloc` and define `input` thus:

```
char input[100];
input[0] = '\0';
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> And there may even be *more* problems, they're just the ones that occurred to me immediately. However, I'd suggest fixing those first since theyre definitely the cause of your segfault.

Then, if there's still problems, come back with another question.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I did what you suggested but the seg fault is still there.
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @GioAFF: one other thing I didn't initially pick up is the casting. Casting malloc return codes is a bad idea at the best of times, casting it to `char` rather than `char *` is almost certainly fatal. See the update. However all those problems should disappear once you  ditch the allocation altogether.

Comment: So, if you still have a problem after implementing my suggestions, comment out the puts and printf at the end to see if it goes away. You may be printing data that hasn't been read/initialised (if fgets returned NULL).

Comment: I changed the allocation memory to static and I still have seg fault. The program doesn't do the fgets. (I used  printf to verify it.)

Comment: @nos 
The data type is char, it comes in strings, probably sent as strings
example: EVENT0290
EVENT02D0
EVENT02D0
EVENT02D0

What exactly do you mean by data format?